# Basic Matching in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working through a book and it gives this example

```
x = "This is a test".match(/(\w+) (\w+)/)
```

We are looking at the parentheses and being able to access what is passed separately.

When I put the expression above into my IRB I get:

> MatchData "This is" 1:"This" 2:"is">

Why doesn't this also include `a` and `Test`?

Would I have to include `.match(/(\w+) (\w+) (\w+) (\w+)/)` ?

Comment: Yes, it matches only first two words as you specified, if you want all word pairs, use something like: `"This is a test".scan(/(\w+)\s+(\w+)/)`

Comment: Awesome, I see what you are doing with that.  Makes a lot of sense, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'match' method is not matching the regex globally. It is only returning the first match. You can use the 'scan' method rather than 'match' and it should return an array of all matches of the regex.

```
[~]$ irb
1.8.7-p371 :001 > x = "This is a test".match(/(\w+) (\w+)/)
 => #<MatchData "This is" 1:"This" 2:"is">
1.8.7-p371 :002 > x = "This is a test".scan(/(\w+) (\w+)/)
 => [["This", "is"], ["a", "test"]]
```